# Can I use the texture mapping result as the new texture data?

Tags: opengl, glfw

I working with OpenGL and "[GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/)" to mapping the texture image to 2D polygon which is the set of vertices generated from OpenCV.

My question is, can I use the result of texture mapping as the new texture (which is already distort by the first mapping) to map with other polygon. 
I think my explanation is so bad, please look at the example;

[image: Original Texture]  [image: After mapping]

Left image is my texture, and the right is the texture after mapping to polygon (the texture divided to 8 block for 8 set of vertices. What I want to do is using the mapping result on the right side as the new texture.

It is possible to do with OpenGL or OpenCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render your scene to a [FBO with a texture attachment, then use that texture to render more geometry](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html#example).

Comment: could you please explain a bit? How the result from texture mapping can be use as new texture using FBO ... I try to read but I really don't understand much. Thank you :)

Comment: When you create and activate a FBO all OpenGL rendering will be rerouted from the main framebuffer onto the FBO.  You can connect a texture to a FBO such that any rendering on the FBO is also done to the texture.  Then you turn off the FBO and bind the texture object like usual and render whatever you want with it onto the main framebuffer.

Comment: Again, I spend today for understand the FBO. However, I have few questions, 1. If texture load from image then mapped to an object (e.g. polygon) then, we use this mapping result to mapping to next object, and continue as long as the program is still running. In this case FBO is possible? 2. As I try to understand, an example shown only when we draw the scene (rendered image, i.e. teapot) and used as an object's texture. But in this case is a bit different, I load the texture and do some mapping and would like to use this result to mapping to next object? It is possible. Thank you.

Comment: First I accept this method seem possible to use for my proposed. However, I didn't try it.

Answer (score 2):

You need 2 FBO and 2 texture.

You render the scene to the first FBO (fbo1) and you send the texture (texture1) to the shader and you render the scene to the second FBO (fbo2). After that you send the seconde texture (texture2) to the shader and render the scene in the main FBO (to display the scene) or in the first FBO (to make another pass).

example :

1) render the scene in FBO1
2) send texture 1 to the shader
3) render the texture 1 modified in FBO2
4) send texture 2 to the shader
5) render the texture 2 modifier in FBO1
6) send texture 1 to the shader
etc, etc...

this is a little code of one of my project to describe what i try to explain (to make a blur).

```
//render the scene to the fbo1
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, f1);
glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
[self drawWithShader:_programRTT];

//apply horizontal blur the result go in the fbo2
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, f2);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t1);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
[self drawWithShader:_programBH];

//apply vertical blur the result go in the fbo1
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, f1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t2);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
[self drawWithShader:_programBV];

//return to the main fbo and display result on screen
[view bindDrawable];
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t1);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
[self drawWithShader:_program];
```

Comment: could you please write some example to loading texture image (just like the picture) to the framebuffer object?, as many examples that I spend a lot of time to tried to understand, i think i understand abit about how there works, but I don't knows much. You example will make me clear. Thank you very much

Comment: When you say "loading texture image to the framebuffer object", do you ask how to give your texture to the shader (which will render your scene) or how to create a texture linked to a framebuffer ?

Comment: How should I explain (sorry for poorly English explanation)? ... Example I create texture object, get textureID and load some picture to this object by "glTexImage2D". Create Framebuffer object, get the fboID, after that, can I load the textureID direct to framebuffer by "glFramebufferTexture2D" point to "textureID" which is loading some image? ... :)

Comment: glFramebufferTexture2D link a texture to the framebuffer so when you render the scene to the framebuffer, the scene will be printed to this texture. If you want to "load" a texture i think you want to display this texture. So you don't send to the framebuffer the texture but in the shader which will display it to the framebuffer.